# Why is "The older desktop computer," better than, "The desktop older computer"?

Tags: word-order

This could be a moderately pedantic point, however, as a native English speaker the word order of,

> The older, desktop computer.

somehow "feels" more correct than

> The desktop, older computer.

Is this just me being odd, or is this an actual rule in English?

To be clear, in this context, one can have a "desktop computer" or a "rack computer".

Comment: Do not answer in comments. Write an answer. It can even be an incomplete germ of an answer, but please put it in the right place.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I did attempt an answer [below](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/575333/377764). From other comments it sounds like it might be incorrect, but I tried :D

Comment: That comment wasn't aimed at you, but rather at the writers of the deleted comments and anyone else who might think about putting the answer in the wrong place. Perhaps I should have used something like "@All", which might be OK until that is actually a relevant username. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @AndrewLeach No worries, I was a little confused!

Answer (score 2):

As BillJ pointed out in a comment, an Attributive Noun + Noun, especially a well-known thing like *shoe store, laptop computer, fire extinguisher*, etc., is rarely separated by an adjective.

Many of these attributive nouns overlap in nature with adjectives of  purpose, but the first (attributive/descriptive) noun forms a practically  inseparable bond with the following noun; the pair defines the thing or concept.

For example:

> A  suitable plastic **table**.
> A  suitable, sturdy, plastic **card
> table**
> (a square table with foldable legs especially suited for (card) games with up to four players).
>
> A successful three-day **sale**
> A successful three-day **fire sale**
> (a sale after destruction/damage of a business by fire)
>
> A long **business letter**  (type of letter)
> Our 18th Annual **Going-Out-Of-Business Sale**
> (humorous **store banner** in a cartoon, but still a type of sale)
>
> We bought giant yellow **water noodles** for the kids.
> (tube-shaped floats for the water).
>
> A **business opportunity**  (a type of opportunity)
> A golden **business opportunity**

Adjectives before the noun + noun still are used in the typical order that grammar books explain to learners of English; however, native speakers use the "correct" order instinctively because usually only one or two "sound right." I don't remember ever being taught the order as a native speaker of English, and I'd have to mentally try out combos to check a grammar book's order.

If we want to invent a rule, you can think of a **no**un + **no**un as if  written noun-noun ( a single thing or concept), with any intervening adjectives a no-no. :-)

And last, but not least (or perhaps least amount of clothing), a hit pop song from 1960:

> An Itsy Bitsy Teenie Weenie Yellow Polka Dot Bikini
>
> [itsy-bitsy] [teenie-weenie] yellow [polka dot] bikini
> (Polka dots: a decorative pattern with large dots).

Answer (score 0):

Adjective order puts age before type.

1. opinion
2. size
3. physical quality
4. shape
5. age
6. colour
7. origin
8. material
9. type
10. purpose

Source: dictionary.cambridge.org. (n.d.). Adjectives: order - English Grammar Today - Cambridge Dictionary. [online] Available at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order).

‌

Comment: 'desktop' is not an adjective, it's a noun-adjunct and syntactically needs to be directly next to the noun it modifies.

Comment: In this context, could "desktop" be a type in the same way that general-purpose, four-sided, U-shaped are types?

Comment: No, because the items you cite are compound adjectives, i.e. single words.

Comment: Is this answer incorrect then? If so, I will gladly delete it.

Comment: @JamesGeddes It seems the data is not incorrect, but it isn't the answer to the question you asked. It answers "blue old computer", where adjectives are ordered badly, but not the case where the "adjective" is a noun adjunct (or "attributive noun").

Comment: @Mitch Agree, this also eliminates the need for the comma since there are not multiple adjectives. It should be "the older desktop computer", not "the older, desktop computer".

Comment: @JamesGeddes I question the numbered list: shape does not come before age. *The old, square table* not *the square, old table.*